# Login screen sometimes appears if user uses back button then clicks link

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

Sometimes, the login screen will appear if the user clicks the back button and then chooses another link, instead of the content that should be displayed.  It's like the application suddenly thinks the user is not authenticated.  The user then has to re-authenticate to continue browsing.  This happens while the user is actively browsing, so no timeout should occur, and after authenticating, the content is shown (so it's not an authorization problem).

This problem is unfortunately quite difficult to reproduce.  The user who has experienced the problem most often is using Windows XP with IE 7, but the problem has also appeared with Windows XP and IE 8.  I can't seem to reproduce the problem on Windows 7 with IE 9 or Chrome 18, but because the problem is difficult to reproduce, I can't say confidently that the problem is browser or browser version dependent.

Our ASP.NET MVC 3 app uses Forms Authentication with role information stored in a SQL Server database, and membership information in Active Directory.  Hosting environment is IIS 7.5 on Windows 2008 R2.

Has anyone else seen this problem, and know of a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

On the server, I guess that you are using a custom IPrincipal which you need to reattach to the request thread for each request? Are you doing this in an HTTPModule or in global.asax? What page event are you hooking into to authorize the thread?

I have noticed differences in authentication being available in different runtime contexts dependent on which event I use. I now always use OnAuthorizeRequest and check that application.Context.User != null.

But the symptoms you are describing sound more like the authorization cookie is missing from the request intermittently.

Add some debug logging for each request and monitor cookies and authorization to see if you can detect the conditions that cause it.